# Python ttk Notebook child not killed after forgotten

Tags: python, memory, tkinter

How to release the object in ttk.Notebook?
I tried to use ttk.Notebook to manage and show multiple images and added close mark to close a tab. However, I found that the object still existed after I close the tab. I called master.forget and destroy. The tab disappeared but the object, the data shown in the object were not deleted. When I checked the task manager, the memory used by Python didn't decrease after that.Below is a sample:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np


class Frame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.data = np.arange(200*512*512).reshape((200, 512, 512))
        self.b = tk.Button(self, text='close', command=self.close)
        self.b.pack()

    def close(self):
        self.master.forget(self.master.select())
        self.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
n = ttk.Notebook(root)
n.pack()
f1 = Frame(n)
f2 = Frame(n)
n.add(f1, text='notebook')
n.add(f2, text='notebook2')
root.mainloop()
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: As long as you have the `f1`, `f2` global variables referring to your frames, they cannot possibly be garbage-collected.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you! I tried `n.add(Frame(n), text='notebook')` without  f1, f2 variables defined. But it is still the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: @jasonharper I just tried not to use notebook widget, just a frame. In this case, when I call destroy, it with its children will be deleted (I didn't define global variables like f1. You are right).  But not sure what should I do with the notebook.

Comment: Possibly, part of the problem is the fact that your frames are part of a reference cycle: Frame -> Button -> `self.close` method -> Frame.  This means that none of the objects will be disposed instantly when they become unreferenced, they have to wait for a garbage collector sweep to find and break the loop.  You could try `import gc; gc.collect()` to force this to happen sooner.  (Note: this is for debugging/educational purposes only.  You should never have to manually invoke GC, as it will automatically happen if the memory is actually needed for something.)

Comment: @jasonharper Yes. This make sense. Thank you! I will try some other methods.